# Split Concatenated, Minified, Uglified JavaScript into Multiple Files with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-uglify, filesplitting

Right now, I have a grunt task for building out my JS application. It uses useminPrepare/usemin to control the concat, minify, and uglify process, and outputs the result as a single output file. This works great for our application.

Now we're trying to do some performance tuning on the application, and hope to split that concatenated, minfied, or uglified JavaScript into N separate files. N would be the optimal size for all the files to concurrently fly through the network from the CDN to the browser as fast as possible.

**Has anyone tried to split uglified JavaScript into multiple files before? What would be the best approach to doing this?**

Comment: Did you solve the problem? seems that oneone have clue about this one :)